# How can I convert scientific notation to decimal in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a number that is represented in scientific notation as 1E-05. I would like to display this value, via ColdFusion, as 0.00001. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

Also worth noting: you can pass any valid number to `PrecisionEvaluate()`.
So, if you have a mix of scientific notation and regular numbers, you are safe to just wrap them all in PrecisionEvaluate().

Examples:

```
PrecisionEvaluate('1E-05') // 0.00001  
PrecisionEvaluate('1E-06') // 0.000001  
PrecisionEvaluate('10') // 10  
PrecisionEvaluate('11.35000') // 11.35000
```

ColdFusion 10 docs (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd9.html)

Comment: Edited with standard 'result' notation to avoid confusion of right hand being set to left via the = sign being interpreted as actual valid code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `PrecisionEvaluate('1E-05')`